# Measurement Problem Explained by Interaction of Operator With Adjoint Having Larger Domain?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

Quantum physics axiomatically uses a self-adjoint operator for a measurement.  In general, the adjoint of an operator has a larger domain than an operator.  Could it be that the "measurement problem, waveform collapse, many-worlds, quantum randomness" enigma is due to the measurement projecting the greater possibilities of the adjoint operations into the space of the measurement operator? In other words, the measurement can only select (by projection) a subset of the range of the adjoint operations, namely the subset that coincides with the domain of the measurement operation. The states of all the adjoint possibilities are unknown, giving rise to the apparent randomness of a measurement.

Is there a topic for this? Is there a name for such an interpretation?  Is anyone promoting it?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question, but note that the measurement problem persists in the finite-dimensional case, e.g. when considering spin measurements (Stern-Gerlach set ups).

Comment: @Tobias Fünke, Thanks.  In that case, I would argue that the projection is one dimensional, so that the measurement selects a one dimensional result from all the adjoints swirling around in unknowable states.

Comment: Quantum mechanics uses self adjoint operators to represent *observables* not *measurements*. Applying the momentum operator to a state does not represent making a measurement of the momentum that state (see for example [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/649924/what-is-the-correspondence-between-operators-and-measurement-in-quantum-mechanic) question). Consequently I don't think what you are suggesting really works